# mvn package executes more tests locally that in bamboo

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, junit, bamboo

I have a spring-boot application which includes JUnit tests and I build using maven. I have organized by JUnit tests in a Suite using `@Suite.SuiteClasses` notation.

My problem/question is why when I run `mvn package` locally, I see that the unit tests referenced by the Suite are executed **but they are also executed as if they were not part of the suite**, while building the code in Bamboo, using again `mvn package` executes the tests only once (i.e. as members of the suite).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use the same profiles / settings / maven commands on bamboo and locally?

I think what happens is that when executing the [package phase](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) the surefire-plugin starts executing all the tests. There might be a naming issue with the [includes](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#includes) the surefire plugin uses by default.

If you execute the maven goal with -X you should be able to see the surefire-plugin configuration it uses to identify the tests. This should only match your suites - not the suites and the tests themselves.

Comment: thank you for your reply @wemu. I have managed to figure it out, by examining the bamboo logs more thoroughly. I realized that all the same number of tests cases have run in bamboo as when I was running it locally. However, when parsing the surefire logs (xml), bamboo does not count the tests that have been run twice (it considers them as one). Therefore the difference. Now I need to find out how to run only the suite and not the individual test cases (surefire configuration).

Comment: I think you only need to change the includes for the surefire-plugin to only match the suite files. That should do.

Comment: Thanks wemu. This did the trick. I excluded *Test.java from the surefile-plugin configuration. The Suite files are named *Tests.java, so these are included.

Comment: glad it helped :)